# how to display values from dynamically created edittext an add

Tags: android

I have created edittext dynamically when i enter the values i am unable to display values the values.If suppose i want add values that i have entered in edit text how is it possible do i need to give for loop.

Here is the code

```
 public class NewActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout ll;

   EditText lEditText; 

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ll=new LinearLayout(this);

            ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my);

            Button lButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtnid);

            lButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            lEditText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

            lEditText.setHint("Text Here");

            lEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            ll.addView(lEditText);


                 }
                });

        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplication());

                          int x=Integer.parseInt(lEditText.getText().toString());

                          tv.setText(x);

                         ll.addView(tv);

            }
        });
```

I am getting errors in logcat as :

```
    AndroidRuntime(509): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at com.app.NewActivity$2.onClick(NewActivity.java:44)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    E/AndroidRuntime(509):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use `lEditText = new EditText(NewActivity.this);` instead of `lEditText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());` and try to set id for dynamically Created EditText

Comment: i am new to android i don't know to set id dynamically please help.

Comment: what is the difference between getApplicationContext() and NewActivity.this what makes the difference how to create set id dynamically

Comment: getApllicationContext will give you the Context and NewActivity.this will give you the Activity. Another thing if you set Id for the view, it will be easy to access it from any part where you dont have access for the object of the view.

Comment: how can add values entered in edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make changes as below  to set the text in your `TextView`

> ```
>  int x=Integer.parseInt(lEditText.getText().toString());
>    tv.setText(x+""); <-- Add "" to set the integer value in your textview.
> ```

**EDITED:**

Try out below code for your dynamically adding values:

> ```
>    final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
>    final EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
>     Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
>     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             try
>             {
>             int x=Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());
>             int y= Integer.valueOf(et2.getText().toString());
>             int z=x+y;
>             System.err.println(z+"");
>                     tv.setText(z+""); 
>             }
>             catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>                 // TODO: handle exception
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Now i am able to display.Now how can add values entered in edittext

Comment: You mean to say that you want append some values in your edittext ?

Comment: yes i want to add values entered in dynamically created edittext

Comment: You can add values in your edittext as `lEditText.append()` method.

Comment: i mean to say not append say i have entered 24 in one edittext and 34 in another edittext i should get total in 58.

Comment: That 58 value should be displayed in the same edittext or in the textview ?

Comment: yes i have checked i am getting force close i d'not know why i am getting should i comment the remaining code

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(391): java.lang.NullPointerException,  E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at com.app.NewActivity$3.onClick(NewActivity.java:66), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123),

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868),  E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626), E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you added the button in your layout and handled its click listener?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer to setText. You need to pass string, if you are passing int, you need to pass resource id.

So use

```
   tv.setText("" + x);
```

instead of

```
   tv.setText(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/) you can see how to use dynamic to get use the setId for the component.